# Are my assets being served from AWS S3

Tags: ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, sinatra, assets

Maybe a really daft question and please dont mark me down for this, but I finally got Heroku to compile its static assets in my S3 bucket with asset_sync.

Now how do i know that the assets are in fact being served from there, I take it theres no magic going on that pulls them in from s3? I have to set the path for each asset prefixed with

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pathto/asset
```

Is there a way to set this in sinatra explicitly, I don't have to manually change every asset do I? that would be silly.

The asset_sync docs say to use this in rails

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

but im not sure how to set this in sinatra

EDIT

```
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require './config/env' if File.exists?('config/env.rb')
require './config/config'
require "rubygems"
require 'sinatra'


configure :development do
AssetSync.config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
end


get '/' do
 erb :index
end

get '/about' do
 erb :about
end
```

This gives the following error in the console

```
 undefined method `action_controller' for #<AssetSync::Config:0x24d1238> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting it in [Sinatra's configure block](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Configuration) via the [Async Built-in initializer](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync#available-configuration-options), e.g:

```
configure :production do
  AssetSync.config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
end
```

It's possible you'll have to call `AssetSync.sync` as well at some point, I'm not sure.

---

Edit: using a configure block.

If you were using a modular app (if not, it's not any different, just remove the `class` bits)

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  configure :development do
    set :this, "and that"
    enable :something
    set :this_only, "gets run in development mode"
  end

  configure :production do
    set :this, "to something else"
    disable :something
    set :this_only, "gets run in production"
    # put your AssetSync stuff in here
  end

  get "/" do
    # …
  end

  get "/assets" do
    # …
  end

  post "/more-routes" do
    # …
  end

  # etc
end
```

See the link I added above for more.

---

`action_controller` is part of Rails. To prefix the path, the best thing you could do is use a helper:

```
helpers do
  def aws_asset( path )
    File.join settings.asset_host, path
  end
end

configure :production do
  set :asset_host, "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
end

configure :development do
  set :asset_host, "/" # this should serve it from the `public_folder`, add subdirs if you need to.
end
```

Then in a route or a view you can do something like this:

```
aws_asset "sprite_number_1.jpg"
```

To use with ERB and [sinatra-static-assets's image_tag](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra-static-assets/1.0.4/Sinatra/StaticAssets/Helpers#image_tag-instance_method):

```
image_tag( aws_asset "sprite_number_1.jpg" )
```

or combine them (this may not work as the `image_tag` helper might not be seen in the scope of the helper, it's easier to try it than to think about it):

```
helpers do
  def aws_image( path )
    image_tag( File.join settings.asset_host, path )
  end
end

# in your view
aws_image( "sprite_number_1.jpg" )
```

I'm sure there'll be an easier way to do this but this will do for a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: do i create a new file for this? or does it go in my app file? not sure where to put this code sorry

Comment: @Richlewis that's ok, it's what StackOverflow is for! :) I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks iain, so in this example i dont need set and enable?, i have updated my question with what i have done so far, and calling AssetSync.sync, does this go at the end of my configure block? I have selected development for now to see if can get working locally. Also getting undefined method AssetSync, but i guess thats because Im not requiring anything yet?

Comment: ok so i required the relevant gems etc but seems as is action_controller is an undefined method?

Comment: @Richlewis yes, ignore the other stuff like `set` and `enable`, it's just there as an example of things you'll see in a `configure` block. Yes, you need to require AssetSync. The error you've got, I think you should post the whole error into your question.

Comment: @Richlewis try `AssetSync.configure` instead of `AssetSync.config`. If that doesn't work [try using the block form](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync#custom-rails-initializer-configinitializersasset_syncrb) e.g. `AssetSync.configure{|config| config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com" }` And maybe try `require 'asset_sync/config'` but that should've been covered by the require you've already done.

Comment: ok so the block method brings back same error ( i take it action_controller is available as part of asset_sync do we know?) using .configure returns

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/asset_sync-b77d9ed0
bcaf/lib/asset_sync/asset_sync.rb:16:in `configure': no block given (yield) (Loc
alJumpError)

Comment: @Richlewis Well, the obvious just occurred to me (I must need more coffee)… `action_controller` is part of _rails_! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Excellent, that clarifies that then.. So thinking about this if we are using a helper and I have to use the helper method on every asset for it to serve from sw3, could i not just have used https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/assetpath on my assets. Also if i have an image that is img src="path" how do i use the helper method within that?

Comment: Thanks for all your help mind, you have done a lot of work :)

Comment: @Richlewis No problem about the help. "could i not just have used s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucketname/assetpath on my assets?" - yes, but if you ever move your assets anywhere else you'll be glad you didn't. Hardcoding is bad because it comes back to bite you on the arse later. Which template language are you using? ERB, Haml…?

Comment: erb, so i just tried <%= image_tag = aws_asset("path") %> think thats right, keep forgetting its ruby at the end of the day :) yes good point about hardcoding. Also is there a way of setting the assets to be served locally for dev and using the helper just for produciton?

Comment: no its not right :( its just outputting a blank image, the linkis appearing in console (firebug) but not the image

Comment: thanks, not sure if you want to add this to answer but in able to use image_tag helper in sinatra we need the gem sinatra-static-assets

Comment: though even now its still giving undefined method :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26550/discussion-between-iain-and-richlewis)

Comment: do you know of a way to call these assets from a .css file, in paticular background-images

Comment: @Richlewis There's a couple of ways I can think of (the easiest probably being [SASS/SCSS templates](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Sass%20Templates), but I think you should open a separate question for that because I think some other people may have good ideas too, and the space for a longer answer and discussion.